# Should I store timezone in separate column in database or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, database

I have an Angular and Node.js application which is highly depends on date and time of users, interact to the system

because of timezone issues, I formated my Angular material datepicker to pass dates in the utc format like this

```
2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z
2020-07-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

and I store it all my dates in this format with (2020-07-27T00:00:00.000Z)

and the time they pick I store it in another column with the following format

```
 (HH:MM)
```

and I have created another column in database where I store timezones like

```
 (America/Toronto)
```

Then I query and concatenate date, time and timezones so to return correct result for user.

I am not sure is there a better way to handle the timezone issues and how to store users data in database with there timezones.

My database table looks like this see image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little more details could clear this up however if you prefer to concatenate for whatever reason maybe just store the yyyy-mm-dd separately from the time

Depending on the use case it is typically bad form to repeatedly store your data or your code. This feels particularly wasteful with databases to store a full yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss and to additionally store separately the exact same time stamp hh:mm somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below example. You can use the `toString()` method to get both the time and the timezone.

```js
var date = "2020-08-26T21:00:00.000Z";
var time = "10:00";

function setDateTimeWithTimezone(date, time) {
  // Convert time string to Date Object
  date = new Date(date);

  // Split minutes and hours
  var splitT = time.split(":");

  // Calculate the total minutes to add
  var min = parseInt(splitT[0]) * 60 + parseInt(splitT[1]);

  // Finaly add the total minutes to your time and get it as string with timezone
  return new Date(date.setMinutes(min)).toString();
}

console.log(setDateTimeWithTimezone(date, time));
```